# how to get a bootstrap button and input group to span the entire width of a column?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I a bootstrap button and input group to span the entire width of a column?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">Ipsum Lorem!</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">

<form class="form-inline">
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <select class="form-control">
        <option>option one</option>
        <option>option two</option>
        <option>option three</option>
        <option>option four</option>
        <option>option five</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" >Add Option</button>
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this example just collapses the select control to the longest length of the input options.

[BootPly here.](http://www.bootply.com/nGTp7jHPC3)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies to you, but I was using Visual Studio 2015 and ran into the same problem with Bootstrap.  I think earlier version of VS may have the same issue.  It is very strange but the ***site.css*** file that comes with the ASP.Net web app template has these lines to limit input element width.  The solution is simply comment this section out.  Hope this helps someone.

```
/* Set widths on the form inputs since otherwise they're 100% wide */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```